# Как обновить сайт подключенный к cloudflare?

Tags: dns, защита, cloudflare, cdn

Проблема состоит в следующем - Есть сайт на движке Wordpress копия которого отдается пользователям с [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/). Если на сайте были проведены изменения с `php/html/css/js`, то пока не зайдешь в аккаунт `cloudflare` и не включишь режим разработчика или же сбросишь кэш будет отдаваться старая версия сайта. Даже если сайт будет удален на хостинге.

Вопрос.

Есть ли возможность заставить сбросить(обновить) кеш в `cloudflare` если доступа к аккаунту на cloudflare нету? (Только есть доступ к хостингу на котором WordPress) Можно ли как-то убедить cloudflare, что необходимо пойти проверить информацию...

Answer (score 1):

Cloudflare не кеширует динамические страницы, только статику (js, css, картинки и т.п.). Ключем кэша является URL.

Подключайте статику с параметром версии и при необходимости приращивайте номер версии. Таким образом вы измените URL и старая версия не будет отдаваться. Например так:

```
<img src="path_to_image?v=123">
<script src="path_to_javascript?v=345">
```